# why does count line shows 0 while file file size if great than 1G?

Tags: csv, unix, cygwin

I have a large csv file about 5G. i want to split it into smaller files to be imported into sqlite.

```
`split -b 1G input.txt output`
```

i got 6 output files from running the above code: output1-output6. the problem is that only output1 has 300K records and all other files have 0. i used the following to count lines in each file:

```
`wc -l output1`
```

but when i check the output file size, all of them are around 1G (except output6). What's wrong with my code or file?

Comment: try `wc -l output*` . (you're not really running your `wc` in back quotes are you? Don't! ;-) . Good luck.

Comment: No. I certainly did not. I ran the same wc code on output1 and I got 300k lines, but when I run it on output2-output6, 0 lines are returned. Strangely, the size of these files are about 1G as expected.

Comment: so `wc -l output*` returned `file1 300,000; file2 0 ; file3 0 ; ....` ? Then agree that there must be line ending problems. First, try `cat -vet file2 | wc -l` if that corrects the count, then `dos2unix file2`. And of course, this scenario indicates that your source file has problems. Did you look at in a an editor? What a pain. Good luck!

Comment: @shelter. Thanks. I got some more info by trying to import this file into SQL server. the error message says that the column data for x1 overflowed the disk I/O buffer. i used `sed -n ...` to look at the record and x1 is not the end of the line...very confused.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting that the other files may have newline character issue(not present). Hence wc command is not able to count the lines(new line character).